# is it possible for LAN and Web to share same database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, ms-access

I have my **MSAccess** Database that is running on LAN.

and i have another **SQL Server Database** running on Web.

my requirement is:

- When any data inserted or updated in **MSAccess**,
   the newly entered or updated data should be updated on **SQL Server Database** as well.

so my question is,

- **How to Synchronize data between these databases?**

Comment: Personally I would ditch MSAccess and keep all your data in SQL Server so there would be no need for any sort of synchronization.

Comment: Yes, MS Access can talk to SQL Server perfectly well; it'll be a lot easier and more stable just to use SQL Server for all your storage. (You can still have a front-end in MS Access, if you need; you just use SQL Server tables instead of Access tables for storage.)

Comment: What version of Access? `.mdb` or `.accdb` file? Can you create linked tables in the Access database to manipulate tables in the SQL Server database?